# html php button generation on the fly, buttons not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

----EDIT-----
Anwser found, instead of buttons i used a href link to pass data onto another php file for the database editing

the following code solved it

```
echo "<tr><td>". $row['NAME'] . " " .  $row['id'] . "</td><td> <a href='edit.php?edit=$i'>Edit</a>
</td>";
```

When generating buttons from a mysql database data.  The buttons themselves dont seem to work with the on click command

```
 $i=0;
 $redirecrurl = 'location.href=\"TestButtonWorks.php\";';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $i= $i+1;
    echo "<tr><td><button class=$i onclick = '$redirecrurl'>  ". $row['NAME'] . " " .  $row['ID'] . " </button></tr></td>";

}
```

I've also tried replacing the webpage link with a function to change the background color that failed to work either

link to page:
https://crucial-creeks.000webhostapp.com/MainPage.php

Its the buttons that are generated in the table that do not work, the buttons on the bottom to add to the list work fine

Full Source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15" />

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 16pt; color="white";}
--->
</STYLE>
<title>Roma</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<font size="3" color="white">
<h1>Pizzaroma</h1>

<?php 
    echo "____________________________________________________________</br>";
    //Connect to database
    require 'Conn.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, NAME FROM Chips");
    echo "</br>To Be Made</br>";
    //Setup Table format
    echo "<table border='1' style='font-family:Georgia, Garamond, Serif;color:white;font-style:italic;'>";


    $i=0;
    $redirecrurl = 'location.href=\"TestButtonWorks.php\";';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //$i To give each buton a specific class
         $i= $i+1;
         //Create button per information in database
        echo "<tr><td><button class=$i onclick = '$redirecrurl'>  ". $row['NAME'] . " " .  $row['id'] . " </button></tr></td>";
    }
    //prints out total amount of orders
    echo $i;
    echo "</table>";
    //Close Database
    mysqli_close($conn);


?>;

<p>____________________________________________________________</p>

</br> 

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='SingleChip.php';"> Single Chip</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='DoubleChip.php';">Double Chip</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='ChipCheese.php';"> Chip Cheese</button>
</br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='GarlicChip.php';"> Garlic Chip</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='GarlicChipCheese.php';">Garlic Chip & Cheese</button>
</br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='ClearTable.php';"> Clear Table</button>

</br>

</br>
<label for="vehicle1">Salt</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Salt2" name="Salt2" value="Salt">
<label for="vehicle1">Vinegar</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Vinegar2" name="Vinegar2" value="Vinegar">
<label for="Well Done">Well Done</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Well Done2" name="Well Done2" value="Well Done">
<label for="Delivery">For Delivery</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Delivery2" name="Delivery2" value="Delivery">
</font>



<script>

function RemoveRow($id){
    echo "FUNCTION CALLED SUCCESSFULLY" $id;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have syntax error with your quotes.

Comment: Worked fine for me and no syntax errors, without having to create a page location.

Answer (score 0):

```
$redirecrurl = 'location.href="TestButtonworks.php"';
echo "<tr><td><button class=$i onclick = '$redirecrurl'>  ". $row['NAME'] . " " .  $row['ID'] . " </button></tr></td>";
```

Comment: Sadly it doesnt resolve the issue, https://crucial-creeks.000webhostapp.com/MainPage.php   The lower buttons add to the data base fine, its just when the buttons are generated they dont seem to want to work after.

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax at `onclick = 'location.href='TestButtonworks.php';'`. You should use `onclick='location.href=\"TestButtonWorks.php\";'` to avoid the comfliction with single quote `'`.

Comment: I've replaced this to your suggestion but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue with the buttons not working.   Under to be made:  it'll show what ever is inside the database, and i'd like those buttons made on the fly to redirect to another page, but its those buttons that seem to not work.  https://crucial-creeks.000webhostapp.com/MainPage.php  <-- the main page

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my problem thanks to a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw1MwUlekeo
Basically you cant use on click buttons whilst creating them dynamically instead use a link and send the primary key information etc on deleting info through php like so

```
echo "<tr><td>". $row['NAME'] . " " .  $row['id'] . "</td><td> <a href='edit.php?edit=$i'>Edit</a>
</td>";
```